# ping Request Timeout causes?

Tags: ping, internet-connection, traceroute

My home internet has recently gone on the fritz.

Running `ping google.com` seems to return interesting results:

```
equest timeout for icmp_seq 2028
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2029
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2030
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2031
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2032
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2033 ttl=108 time=53.390 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2034 ttl=108 time=48.291 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2035 ttl=108 time=50.837 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2036 ttl=108 time=69.423 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2037 ttl=108 time=61.792 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2038 ttl=108 time=51.684 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2039 ttl=108 time=55.885 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2040 ttl=108 time=58.286 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2041 ttl=108 time=56.756 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2042 ttl=108 time=68.196 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2043 ttl=108 time=52.977 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2044 ttl=108 time=53.858 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2045 ttl=108 time=69.533 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2046 ttl=108 time=51.075 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2047 ttl=108 time=58.308 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2048 ttl=108 time=69.271 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2049 ttl=108 time=72.709 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2050 ttl=108 time=78.099 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2051 ttl=108 time=67.152 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2052 ttl=108 time=58.480 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2053 ttl=108 time=69.392 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2054 ttl=108 time=72.309 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.46: icmp_seq=2055 ttl=108 time=101.416 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2056
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2057
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2058
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2059
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2060
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2061
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2062
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2063
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2064
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2065
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2066
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2067
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2068
```

Running `traceroute google.com` presents the following (first one ping was responding fine, second one was getting Request Timeout):

```
MacBook-Pro$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.72.46), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.195.1 (192.168.195.1)  2.623 ms  1.741 ms  2.892 ms
 2  100.100.97.33 (100.100.97.33)  34.139 ms  15.495 ms  39.683 ms
 3  136.175.96.40 (136.175.96.40)  87.983 ms  15.359 ms  88.080 ms
 4  136.175.96.28 (136.175.96.28)  16.773 ms  15.865 ms  15.815 ms
 5  136.175.96.14 (136.175.96.14)  16.291 ms  31.518 ms  23.569 ms
 6  10ge7-18.core1.slc1.he.net (64.71.148.5)  23.881 ms  103.494 ms  80.173 ms
 7  100ge9-1.core1.den1.he.net (72.52.92.41)  48.007 ms  32.146 ms  31.680 ms
 8  206.51.46.95.any2ix.coresite.com (206.51.46.95)  56.002 ms
    206.53.175.53 (206.53.175.53)  47.809 ms
    google.any2.coresite.com (206.51.46.3)  51.853 ms
 9  108.170.254.65 (108.170.254.65)  55.198 ms *
    108.170.254.81 (108.170.254.81)  69.463 ms
10  172.253.75.177 (172.253.75.177)  47.651 ms  49.026 ms  56.450 ms
11  den16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.72.46)  47.506 ms  47.040 ms
    108.170.252.203 (108.170.252.203)  87.779 ms
MacBook-Pro$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.72.46), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.195.1 (192.168.195.1)  2.110 ms  1.734 ms  1.557 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  136.175.96.28 (136.175.96.28)  20.364 ms  30.022 ms  24.279 ms
 5  136.175.96.14 (136.175.96.14)  16.071 ms  38.877 ms  30.850 ms
 6  10ge7-18.core1.slc1.he.net (64.71.148.5)  16.949 ms  44.295 ms  57.805 ms
 7  100ge9-1.core1.den1.he.net (72.52.92.41)  93.159 ms  36.219 ms  46.582 ms
 8  206.53.175.53 (206.53.175.53)  125.673 ms
    206.51.46.95.any2ix.coresite.com (206.51.46.95)  127.034 ms
    206.53.175.23 (206.53.175.23)  72.384 ms
 9  108.170.254.81 (108.170.254.81)  77.559 ms  70.112 ms *
10  172.253.75.177 (172.253.75.177)  63.062 ms  63.508 ms
    209.85.142.171 (209.85.142.171)  47.790 ms
11  den16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.72.46)  48.123 ms
    108.170.252.201 (108.170.252.201)  63.219 ms
    den16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.72.46)  48.544 ms
MacBook-Pro$
```

Not being a network engineer, I was hoping someone could help me understand what might be going on with either my router or my ISP?

Comment: Do you have some connection heavy things running behindert your router? I sometimes  encountered similar behaviour when running a Tor node.

Comment: Not today. Just trying to stream netflix.

Comment: Not today. Just trying to stream netflix.

Comment: Not today. Just trying to stream netflix.